# Compare two arrays and append last values if they are the same else value zero

Tags: php, arrays

I have two string values namely $late_array and $wrong_array. The values are comma delimited.
What I would like to do is compare the two arrays and if the first two elements are the same add the value to the end else make it zero. The arrays I have:

```
$late_array = array(
            [0] => 140610d,Richard,12
            [1] => 140610a,Dave,22
            [2] => 140610n,Noddy,121
            [3] => 140610a,Nick,15
 )
 $wrong_array = array(
            [0] => 140610d,Richard,2
            [1] => 140610d,Mary,60
            [2] => 140610a,Dave,11
            [3] => 140610n,Noddy,90
 )
```

The end result should be:

```
 $combined_array = array(
            [0] => 140610d,Richard,12,2
            [1] => 140610d,Mary,0,60
            [2] => 140610a,Dave,22,11
            [3] => 140610a,Nick,15,0
            [4] => 140610n,Noddy,121,90
  )
```

I have so far formed a foreach and used the '===' operators to check if the date and name match then output as I want but I have not been able to get it to work if the name is not present in one array but another to make the value zero.

EDIT: Just to clear it up, hopefully. If the value is present in both arrays then the date,name,late value,wrong value should show. But if the value is present in late only then the value for wrong should be 0, same visa versa. Added "Nick" to try and explain a bit better.

This is what I did to solve the problem so far:

```
$wrong_val = array();
foreach($out as $wrong_value) { 
    $wrong_tosearch[] = substr($wrong_value,0,strrpos($wrong_value,",")); 
    $w_id = substr($wrong_value,0,strrpos($wrong_value,","));
    $wrong_val[$w_id] = substr($wrong_value,strrpos($wrong_value,",")+1,strlen($wrong_value));
}
foreach($sql_late_array as $late_value) {
    $late_tosearch[] = substr($late_value,0,strrpos($late_value,","));
    $l_id = substr($late_value,0,strrpos($late_value,","));
    $late_val[$l_id] = substr($late_value,strrpos($late_value,",")+1,strlen($late_value));
}
$merge = array_merge($wrong_tosearch,$late_tosearch);
$sort = array_values(array_unique($merge));

$combined_array = array();
foreach ($sort as $search_val) {
    if (array_key_exists($search_val,$wrong_val) !== FALSE) {
        foreach ($wrong_val as $w_key=>$w_val) {
            $combined_array[$w_key]['late'] = "0";
            $combined_array[$w_key]['wrong'] = $w_val;
        }
    }
    if (array_key_exists($search_val,$late_val) !== FALSE) {
        foreach ($late_val as $l_key=>$l_val) {
            $combined_array[$l_key]['wrong'] = "0";
            $combined_array[$l_key]['late'] = $l_val;
        }
    }
}
print_r($combined_array);
```

Comment: You trying to compare strings. What is format of those strings?

Comment: the string in the array is the date+(d)day/(a)afternoon/(n)night, persons name, late/wrong value

Comment: in the `$combined_array` why is `140610d,Mary,0,60` like that? mary is  alone where did the zero came from?

Comment: That is what I'm trying to output. If Mary has no value in any array then default to zero otherwise use the value

Comment: Your `combined_array` does not match the description you provided (append a `0` if they don't match). Can you clear it up? For example, you appended `60` to `Mary` instead of `0`. Similar for `Nobody`, which should have gotten a `0`.

Comment: I have added to the question. Sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if below code solves your problem.

```
$late_array = array(
        "0" => "140610d,Richard,12",
        "1" => "140610a,Dave,22",
        "2" => "140610n,Noddy,121"
 );
    $wrong_array = array(
        "0" => "140610d,Richard,2",
        "1" => "140610d,Mary,60",
        "2" => "140610a,Dave,11",
        "3" => "140610n,Noddy,90"
 );

 foreach($wrong_array as $wv)
 { 
  $tosearch = substr($wv,0,strrpos($wv,",")-1); 
  $valtoadd = substr($wv,strrpos($wv,",")+1,strlen($wv)); 

  $added=false;
  foreach($late_array as $lv)
  {
     if(strstr($lv, $tosearch) !== false) 
     {  
        $combined_array[] = $lv.",".$valtoadd; 
        $added=true;
        break;
     }
  }
  if(!$added)
    $combined_array[] = $tosearch.",0,".$valtoadd; 
  }

  $tcombined_array = $combined_array; 
  foreach($late_array  as $wv)
  {
  $added = false;   
  foreach($tcombined_array  as $cv)
    if(strstr($cv,$wv)) 
     $added = true; 

  if(!$added) $combined_array[] = $wv.",0";
  } 

  print_r($combined_array);
```

Comment: Thanks this works, one question though, what if an extra entry is added to the late array? It seems to skip it?

Comment: Updated code and added check for missing elements from first array

Answer (score 0):

May be big but works

```
<?php
$late_array = array(
        0 => "140610d,Richard,12",
        1 => "140610a,Dave,22",
        2 => "140610n,Noddy,121",
 );
 $wrong_array = array(
        0 => "140610d,Richard,2",
        1 => "140610d,Mary,60",
        2 => "140610a,Dave,11",
        3 => "140610n,Noddy,90"
 );

 $pattern = "/[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*,[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*,/";
$combined_array = $late_array;
foreach($wrong_array as $wrong_index => $wrong_value){
    foreach($late_array as $late_index => $late_value){
        preg_match_all($pattern, $late_value, $late_matches);
        preg_match_all($pattern, $wrong_value, $wrong_matches);

       if($late_matches[0] == $wrong_matches[0]){
           $explode = explode(',',$wrong_value);
           $combined_array[$late_index] = $combined_array[$late_index].','.$explode[2];
           $matchedValues[] = $wrong_index;
       }
    }
}

$unmatched_values = array_diff(array_keys($wrong_array), array_values($matchedValues));
foreach($unmatched_values as $key => $value){
    $combined_array[] = $wrong_array[$value].',0';
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($combined_array);
?>
```